# Can't push my project on GitHub using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github

I can't perform the initial push of my Android project:

```
Can't finish GitHub sharing process
 Successfully created project '****' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
 Error: Could not find or load main class org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp
 unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\git-askpass-0.bat'
 failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
 could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
```

Comment: 1 - close `AS` and opened as `Administrator` ,  2- seems you not config you git correctlly

Comment: @Hosseini . Opened as `Administrator`. Doesn't work. It worked with these settings before.

Comment: its seems now dosen't `could not read Username for https://github.com` , please check this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, to solve this you run the following commands on git:

```
git config --global user.email "example@example.com"

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you start working on android studio , register your username and user-email on git bash.(that's where the error is coming from).
   focus on phase - xx below , but if you haven't done 1 & 2 go through them as well . Also , you can check phase 4 , 5.

**Phase** 1- **github.com**    register with username , user-email and password.

**Phase** 2 - git-scm.com/downloads   with selections as -get desktop icon , use git from git bash only , check out windows style ,use mintty .....

**Phase xx**- 
In git bash ,type where your current cursor is:-

**git config --global user.name "jamesbond"**
Press enter
Type (don't undo the previous step) where your cursor is again...
  **git   config --global  user.email  "jamesbond@gmail.com"**
Press enter 
And leave it just like that.
Notes(for phase xx) :--
Again , do work on gitbash before you start opening android studio . 
You have to enter your username and password(of github.com account) instead of jamesbond.

Be careful with spacing and all small letters.

**phase** 4 --in android studio click on
Vcs--> import into version control -->share project on github. ---> you can give description and press share.--> make sure all files are checked and can add commit message and press ok.--> you should be the getting a success message.

**phase** 5-- to check the real code
Open your github account at github.com---> you will find a box of your repositories ----> click on your project and keep clicking the further ones. --->app-->>src-->>main-->>java/edu/pushup (this may be different for you)-->> mainactivity.java    and you will see your code...

Comment: Please check help section to learn how to use markdown to format your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows
First, remove git from your project
How to remove .git from the project

1. Open cmd in the project folder
2. Run Following Command rd /s /q ".git"

Now Open Android Studio>Files>Setting>Version Control>Git
Enable user credential helper

Now add git and share the project to Github (Check commit error first)